# Parse large XML file with java

Tags: java, stax

I'm trying to read a huge XML file(2GB). So, I started of to use STAX and I've to use steam input. Below is the code

```
filePath = "D:/Data/sample.xml"; //Correct path
String tagContent = null;
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = null;
try{
    System.out.println("here");
    reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filePath));
    System.out.println("Reader1:" + reader);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error 4:" + e);
}
System.out.println("Reader2:" + reader);
```

Output returns error:

```
here
Error 4:javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.net.MalformedURLException
Reader2:null
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: How does `filePath` look?

Comment: I don't like your output. The second "Reader: null" doesn't come from the code you've pasted.

Comment: I've made some corrections.

Answer (score 3):

Method `getSystemResourceAsStream` *opens for reading, a resource of the specified name from the search path used to load classes*.

You are going to read a file so open a file stream:

```
        filePath = "D:/Data/sample.xml"; //Correct path
        String tagContent = null;
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader reader = null;
        try{
            System.out.println("here");
            reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));
            System.out.println("Reader:" + reader);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error 4:" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Reader:" + reader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line appears to be throwing an exception

reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filePath));

which causes reader to remain null. Most probably class loading is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you filepath is not a valid [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax): try with : `file:///D:/Data/sample.xml`

Comment: Change `System.out.println("Error 4:" + e);` by `System.out.println("Error 4:" + e.getMessage());` to check what is failing

Answer (score 0):

`ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(...)` is using the `system` `classloader`. Just use `this.getClass().getResoruceAsStream(...)`.